# How to configure parameters of Flink job on application level?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

Can we configure parameters such as `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots` and `taskmanager.memory.process.size` in the application level?

I  know that parallelism can be configured in application level. How about the other parameters and how to do it in Scala?

Comment: Quite frankly I don't think you can set these values while your job are running. Based on my understanding these values are used when the TaskManager instances are provisioned.

Answer (score 0):

[FLIP-169: DataStream API for Fine-Grained Resource Requirements](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/MI3OCg) will bring some new capabilities along these lines when it lands in Flink 1.14.